# How I can put "Imagenview" under all the elements?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

[image]

Hi, I commented that I have this layout and if you can see there is a line on the right which should go below the text

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_promocion_item0"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#363636"
android:padding="10dip" >
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/contenido"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contenido_Nombre"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".75"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        >
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/nombre_promo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Vodka + Nectar"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:tag="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contenido_precio"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >       
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/separador_lateral"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/> 
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/precio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="$2200"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            />        
    </LinearLayout>
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/separador"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="19dp"
    android:layout_weight=".50"
    android:src="@drawable/divierblanco" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>     
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

.. so is something like:

```
NAME: PRICE
```

---

I can not locate the image below the text .... Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have way too many nested `LinearLayouts`, IMHO, which can be bad for performance and decrease readability. I would use a `RelativeLayout` and 1 nested `LinearLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
   ...>
    <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/someId"
       ....
        <TextView
           ...>
        <ImageView
           ...>
        <TextView
           ...>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_below="id/someId"
        ...>
```

Something like this should work.

**Alternatively** if this doesn't work for you, then placing that `ImageVIew` outside of the first child `LinearLayout` should also work

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_promocion_item0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#363636"
    android:padding="10dip" >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/contenido"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contenido_Nombre"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".75"
            android:orientation="horizontal" > 

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/nombre_promo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Vodka + Nectar"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:tag="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contenido_precio"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >       
            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/separador_lateral"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/> 
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/precio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="$2200"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="24dp" />

        </LinearLayout>     
      </LinearLayout>
      <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/separador"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="19dp"
         android:layout_weight=".50"
         android:src="@drawable/divierblanco" 
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>  // this doesn't do anything in a LinearLayout

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If I make the second alternative, the image disappears

Comment: Ah yes, you would have to change the `width` and remove the `weight`. But you have it inside of a `LinearLayout` with a horizontal `orientation` so that's why it is showing to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Your imageView (with the id separador) is inside a linearLayout with an orientation set to "horizontal". Move the imageView to the outermost linearlayout like so:

EDIT: The xml that's displayed below is completely different than what I typed in my answer. What's up with that? Regardless, move the imageView down an element.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/contenido"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contenido_Nombre"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".75"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nombre_promo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag="bold"
            android:text="Vodka + Nectar"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contenido_precio"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/separador_lateral"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:src="@drawable/vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/precio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="$2200"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/separador"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="19dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_weight=".50"
    android:src="@drawable/divierblanco" /></LinearLayout>
```